# Is it possible to resume a communication in WebRTC if one of the two participants closed the browser window?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webrtc

I have created a WebRTC connection where I can send messages and video to the other party, but if one of the two disconnects, then there can be no communication, even if the response that the other party sent me at the beginning is accepted again. but it still doesn't work.

Is it possible or not to resume that communication without having to redo the connection process and having to send the sdp to the other party again?

Part of the data I'm sending::

```
const connection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] });


async function start() {

const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});

localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    connection.addTrack(track, localStream);
});

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the browser window is closed it is dead for good. You can not recover from that without going through the signalling process again.

The original signalling process sends messages across including randomized ID's and TCP/UDP ports. They lose their meaning in the moment the object is destroyed.